# Dremio date conversation

Tags: sql, dremio

How to convert date field "Dec 1 2018 6:38PM" to `dd-mm-yyyy` (01-12-2018)` in Dremio?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @Ponni that's a little strange choice, maybe you meant [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: You have tagged your question with sql so what DBMS are you using? Please tag your question with the correct database so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_timestamp('Dec 1 2018 6:38PM','mon dd yyyy hh:miAM')
```

Date/Time formats here: https://docs.dremio.com/sql-reference/sql-functions/datetime-formats.html